# Testng marked a test as success when it should fail

Tags: java, netbeans, testng, dataprovider

I have test code as below. test1 passes the test but test2 failed when I expect both to fail. Can anyone please explain why this happens?

```
@Test(dataProvider="prov")
public void test1(int x, int y){
    System.out.println("x=" + x + ", y=" + y);
    assertEquals(x + y, 3);
}

@Test(dataProvider="prov")
public void test2(int x, int y){
    System.out.println("x=" + x + ", y=" + y);
    assertEquals(x + y, 7);
}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] prov(){
    return new Object[][]{
        {1,2},
        {3,4}
    };
}
```

Comment: You've got diagnostics in there - what gets printed?

Comment: x=1, y=2
x=3, y=4
x=1, y=2
x=3, y=4

Comment: Okay, so both tests are being executed. I'd expect to see two invocations of each test, one passing and one failing... are you sure you're not just seeing the first invocation of each method within your test runner results?

Comment: That's the problem. I expects both method to be invoked twice and since each of the method will have one failed invocation, I expects both method to fail. But in the end I got test1 pass and test2 failed.

Comment: I tested it by using testng-6.3.1 in idea 10.5. Both two methods are failure, and there are really two invocations , one success and the other failure. Maybe there are something wrong in your project or just there are something you don't see .

Comment: What are you running the test in?

Comment: I tested using testng-6.2.1 in netbeans 7.1

Comment: Try running your test on the command line and also use the latest version of TestNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bingo! This is a netbeans bug. In command line, both tests failed.

Off to report the bug now...